# Is it possible to browse samba resources in command line?

Tags: command-line, samba

I would like to browse Samba server resources from my command line. I guess this is possible, though not that sure if I could `cd` to smb directories. Do I need any special package to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The software, `smbclient`, can do this.

```
smbclient -L 192.168.1.100 -U administrator
```

Above, the result should be a list of shares. If no username was specified, `smbclient` uses the current username. Below, the result should be an SMB prompt, `smb: \>`. Type `h` for help. It's much like an FTP client.

```
smbclient //192.168.1.100/SharedDocuments -U administrator
```

It is also possible to mount a Samba share with `smbmount`. These programs may need to be installed, but the name of the package depends on the package manager.